# Is there a never-null unique owner of heap allocated objects?

Tags: c++, architecture, null, heap-memory, smart-pointers

Currently, I'm storing a collection of `std::unique_ptr`s to heap allocated objects of a polymorphic type:

```
struct Foo {
  virtual ~Foo() = default;
};
Collection<std::unique_ptr<Foo>> foos;
```

The basic interface I need is putting / taking owners of `Foo` to / from `foos`. The objects stored in `foos` are never supposed to be `nullptr` so I'd like to replace runtime `assert(owner_taken)` with compile-time checks. Moreover, I would like to be capable of using non-null owners in the context where a nullable one may be expected.

Probably, I need to store something like `unique_ref` but how would I extract one from `foos`? I don't want a copy, I want the stored object itself, so `owner->clone()` isn't a solution. Neither I can `std::move(owner)` because the state of a "unique reference" would be invalid afterwards.

Is there a clean design decision?

Comment: If you don't allow a non-owning state in the never-null unique owner, then you can never move from it, because there wouldn't be any valid state for that. So such a type would always be non-movable. Is that really what you want? Would the collection work with non-movable types?

Comment: As a compromise, you could make your own nullptr-throwing unique_ptr that will throw when it holds a nullptr and an attempt to access the nullptr it is made or throw if attempted construction with a nullptr.  (For example, after having its innards moved out from within, leaving behind an empty husk.)

Comment: @walnut it's still nice if I'm suggested anything else which still provides compile-time guarantees of non-nullability in cases when one is needed.

Comment: But can your collection handle immovable types? E.g. `std::vector` can't.

Comment: @Eljay I'm afraid it's too close to `assert(owner)` which I want to avoid.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I'm usually using `std` ones but I'm open for more suitable alternatives. As I know, `map` allows to `extract()` even immovable types, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, or you can use `std::list` if you don't need a map.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat it's inspiring yet I still have to find a suitable `Owner<T>` :)

Comment: If you can consider alternative programming languages, Rust supports the idiom you are looking for.

Comment: @Eljay it would be too radical I'm afraid :D How does Rust allow this feature? I don't think it is impossible to emulate it using C++.

Comment: Rust has the feature of a strong ownership model.  Attempting to access a variable that has been moved from is a compile-time error.  I don't know how you would emulate it using C++, as it is a language feature of Rust that is checked at compile-time.

Comment: Part of the strong ownership model in Rust is a feature called "[type state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210025/what-is-typestate)".

Comment: `extract()` from `std::map` returns a [node handle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/node_handle) which can also be empty and accessing an empty node handle is _undefined behavior_. So it has very similar semantics as a `std::unique_ptr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a never-null unique owner of heap allocated objects?

There is no such type in the standard library.

It is possible to implement such type. Simply define a type with unique_ptr member and mark the default constructor deleted. You can mark constructor from `std::nullptr_t` deleted also so that construction from `nullptr` will be prevented at compile time.

Whether you construct from an external pointer, or allocate in the constructor, there is no alternative for checking for null at runtime.

Comment: What about references? `T&` is guaranteed to never be null.

Comment: @passing_through Not in legal code, but it's unfortunately easy to write [illegal code](https://ideone.com/1bYOnq).

Comment: @user4581301 actually, examples like the one you've provided are why I'm here trying to use references rather than pointers: I can be sure they aren't null. If my question has an answer with all the expected features, I can limit using pointers to only the cases when a value can actually be null so it's not a pain to always check that special case.

Comment: @passing_through I would strongly recommend against taking ownership of addresses of objects through references. Too easy to accidentally pass non-owned objects such as automatic ones.

Comment: @eerorika you're right: just because of this danger I want a special pseudo-reference owner class (instead of just `&`) for owning objects on the heap.

Answer (score -1):

Reading your question, I interpret the following requirements:

1. You don't want to copy or move the object itself (`Foo`)
2. You don't want a wrapper which has some sort of empty state which excludes move semantics
3. The object itself (`Foo`) should be stored on the heap such that its lifetime is independent of the control flow
4. The object itself (`Foo`) should be deleted once it is not used any more

As construction / destruction, copy and move are the only ways to get objects into / out of a container, the only thing left is a wrapper object which is copied when moved into / out of the container.

You can create such an object yourself as follows:

```cpp
// LICENSE: MIT

#include <memory>
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
class shared_ref {
public:
    template<typename ...Args>
    shared_ref(Args&&... args)
        : data{new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...)} 
    {}
    shared_ref(shared_ref&&) = delete;
    shared_ref& operator=(shared_ref&&) = delete;

    T& get() noexcept {
        return *data;
    }
    const T& get() const noexcept {
        return *data;
    }

    operator T&() noexcept {
        return get();
    }
    operator const T&() const noexcept {
        return get();
    }

    void swap(shared_ref& other) noexcept {
        return data.swap(other);
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> data;
};

template<class T>
void swap(shared_ref<T>& lhs, shared_ref<T>& rhs) noexcept {
    return lhs.swap(rhs);
}
```

I leave it as an exercise to the reader to add support for `Allocator`, `Deleter`, `operator[]`, *implicit conversion contructor to base classes*.

This can then be used as follows:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    shared_ref<int> r;  // default initialized
    std::cout << "r=" << r << std::endl;
    r = 5;  // type conversion operator to reference
    std::cout << "r=" << r << std::endl;

    shared_ref<int> s{7};  // initialized with forwarded arguments
    std::cout << "s=" << s << std::endl;

    std::swap(r, s);
    std::cout << "r=" << r << ", " << "s=" << s << std::endl;

    s = r;  // copy assignment operator
    std::cout << "s=" << s << std::endl;

    const shared_ref<int> t{s}; // copy constructor
    std::cout << "t=" << t << std::endl;
    //t = 8;  // const ref from a const object is immutable
    
    return 0;
}
```